# Build failed with an exception

Tags: android, gradle

I am getting Task 'jar' is ambiguous in root project 'ProjectName'.

Candidates are: 'jarDebugClasses', 'jarReleaseClasses'.

while i run  ./gradlew clean jar

can anybody help me out.

Comment: maybe ./gradlew clean jar* ? A bit more information would be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error information basically says what is wrong: gradle cannot determine which task you are trying to run as `jar` is short for both `jarDebugClasses` as well as `jarReleaseClasses`. Replacing jar with `jarR` will solve the ambiguity (if you want to trigger the `jarReleaseClasses` task - use `jarD` for `jarDebugClasses`).